# Using the logic analyser in Keil uVision5 with an STM32 nucleo F030R8

Tags: stm32, arm

As the title says, I'm attempting to use the logic analyser that is built-in in the uVision5 with the above development board.

The debugger that I am using is the on-board ST-Link Debugger. When I am on the trace tab, most options are greyed out. I select "trace enable" and then attempt to run the debugger but I get the error "HW not present". I have seen tutorials that have the trace events available to select, and they are using the same debugger (but a different development board).

I can get everything up and running as I like if I use a simulator, so it's something hardware or configuration related.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe the ST-Link Debugger doesn't support HW trace? Or perhaps the processor itself does not support HW trace?

Comment: I assumed that maybe that would be the case but all the examples that I've seen have used the ST-Link debugger. How can I find out if the processor itself is not supported? Obviously the data sheet won't tell you what it doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and thought that i might as well add it here in case someone else has a similar question. Any devices with a Cortex M0 or M0+ will not be able to support this function despite the debugger itself supporting it. If this function is required it is recommended to avoid M0 based development boards and go for M4 development boards. For example I have replaced the Nucleo F030R8 with a Nucleo F411RE and now have no problems.